# Timestamp to current date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, timestamp

I am making a simplified facebook/twitter like website and i'm trying to convert a timestamp into the current date using javascript. The timestamp is stored in the msg variable and i am wanting to convert it to the current Date UTC.

```
var msg = new Date(timestamp);
```

Now how to convert it anybody?

I want the code or the formula i could use that will produce the current date.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in `.toUTCString()` method of `Date`:

```
var msg = new Date(timestamp).toUTCString();
alert(msg); // "Thu, 09 Oct 2014 14:58:21 GMT"
```

Comment: im getting invalid date

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid date"? Are you sure your timestamp variable is in the correct format (number of milliseconds)?

Comment: the timestamp im getting is from the Amazon cloud server using ActiveMQ MOM. I got it working had to use 'timestamp*1000' but it is still giving me the wrong time.

For example 1412895091488 should give me "Thu, 09 Oct 2014 23:10:45 GMT"

But instead im getting "Wed, 25 Nov 46742 19:24:08 GMT"

Comment: That's another kind of problem then... although my browser (Chrome) gives me "Thu, 09 Oct 2014 22:51:31 GMT" for the timestamp you mentioned. I can't tell what's going wrong without seeing the rest of your code, sorry.

Comment: Marco you are correct. LearnerBeware i think you're multiplying your timestamp with 1000 twice. That explains the year 46742. Since you probably get your timestamp in seconds you probably need to multiply it just once (in case you get it in milliseconds directly you don't need to multiply it at all).